# Sequelize.js - Generate field value on save

Tags: sequelize.js

Currently I have an SQL query that generates a value for a column called seqid, based on its actual content:

```
INSERT into invoices(seqid) SELECT concat(year(CURDATE()),'-',lpad(ifnull(max(convert(substr(seqid,6), UNSIGNED INTEGER)+1),1),4,0)) FROM invoices where seqid like concat(year(CURDATE()),'-%')
```

Basically it creates records in the following format:

> 2019-0001 2019-0002 2019-0003 2020-0001 2021-0001...

I would like to achieve the same result using sequelize. But I can't find how in the docs. Can sequelize.literal can used for such a case, or a hook, or a mix of both.
Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: Using hooks like this works:

    beforeSave: async (instance,options)=>{
        let year=new Date().getFullYear()
        let index = await Invoice.count('seqid',{where:{seqid: {[Op.like]: `${year}-%`}}})
        instance.seqid=[year,Number(index+1).toString().padStart(4,0)].join('-');
    }

But, the fair question is: is it really a good practice to call <model>.count inside a hook, which leads to 2 SQL queries, one for the count and a final one for the save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hooks like this works:

```
beforeSave: async (instance,options)=>{
    let year=new Date().getFullYear()
    let offset= await Invoice.count('seqid',{where:{seqid: {[Op.like]: `${year}-%`}}})
    instance.seqid=[year,Number(offset+1).toString().padStart(4,0)].join('-');
}
```

But, the fair question is: is it really a good practice to call .count inside a hook, which leads to 2 SQL queries, one for the count and a final one for the save